# Joining geodatabase table and csv file in a "one-to-many" type of relationship using arcpy

Tags: join, one-to-many

I have a geodatabase table with the following attributes:

| Name | KP |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 500 |
| A2 | 750 |
| A3 | 340 |

and  I have a csv file with the following attributes

| cptName | top_m | thick_m | base_m | Lith |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2 | 0.2 | 2.2 | blue |
| A1 | 2.2 | 0.4 | 2.6 | yellow |
| A1 | 2.6 | 0.1 | 2.7 | pink |
| A2 | 1.3 | 0.8 | 2.1 | grey |
| A2 | 2.1 | 1.2 | 3.3 | green |
| A3 | 4 | 2.5 | 6.4 | red |
| A3 | 6.4 | 1.5 | 7.9 | blue |
| A3 | 7.9 | 0.9 | 8.8 | green |

What I would like to achieve is that if the "Name" field value in the gdb table is equal
to the "cptName" field values in the csv file then the "KP" value should be assigned to "Xlith"

for example:
A1 from gdb table = A1 in csv file, then you have the following

| cptName | top_m | thick_m | base_m | Lith | Xlith |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2 | 0.2 | 2.2 | blue | 500 |
| A1 | 2.2 | 0.4 | 2.6 | yellow | 500 |
| A1 | 2.6 | 0.1 | 2.7 | pink | 500 |

How can I do this using python?